# Does this code soln pass for the case when all values in matrix is negative

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I was reading this interview question and its solution and I feel like this solution fails for the case when all values in the given matrix is negative as in that case output will be given to be zero. Can someone please confirm if this is true ?

This is the link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-cost-path-from-the-bottom-left-corner-to-the-top-right-corner/

Answer (score 0):

It does fail, because the extra array should be initialized to `-INT_MIN`. This solution is pretty bad overall, O(n^2) memory complexity and it always enqueues values even though value might've not been updated. It also may suffer from extra array being of `int` values and not `long`, because some path's weight may exceed an `int`.